# Could not set DHCPv4 route: Nexthop has invalid gateway. Network is unreachable

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dhcp, systemd, route

**/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml**

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

**/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-ens192.network**

```
[Match]
Name=ens192

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=100
UseMTU=true
```

**ip -4 a**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 217.160.244.97/32 scope global dynamic ens192
       valid_lft 39392sec preferred_lft 39392sec
```

**ip -4 route**

```
default via 10.255.255.1 dev ens192 proto dhcp src 217.160.244.97 metric 100
10.255.255.1 dev ens192 proto dhcp scope link src 217.160.244.97 metric 100
```

**service systemd-networkd status**

```
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-05-11 06:30:58 UTC; 1h 5min ago
TriggeredBy: ● systemd-networkd.socket
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
   Main PID: 928 (systemd-network)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38422)
     Memory: 3.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
             └─928 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

May 11 06:30:58 local systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
May 11 06:30:58 local systemd-networkd[928]: Enumeration completed
May 11 06:30:58 local systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
May 11 06:30:58 local systemd-networkd[928]: ens192: IPv6 successfully enabled
May 11 06:30:58 local systemd-networkd[928]: ens192: Link UP
May 11 06:30:58 local systemd-networkd[928]: ens192: Gained carrier
May 11 06:30:58 local systemd-networkd[928]: ens192: DHCPv4 address 217.160.244.97/32 via 10.255.255.1
May 11 06:30:58 local systemd-networkd[928]: ens192: Could not set DHCPv4 route: Nexthop has invalid gateway. Network is unreachable
May 11 06:30:58 local systemd-networkd[928]: ens192: Failed
```

I don't know how to solve that issue! I've been trying to solve it for few days ago but still not able to figure it out.

Comment: It looks like you are using IONOS aka 1&1. They use an unusual IPv4 networking setup and you will probably need help from their support to solve this. AFAIK they don't provide any technical support for using systemd-networkd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found adding "critical: true" in file: /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
ensure that the interface did not regularly go down (seems like an issue with IONOS). The file should look like:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: true
      critical: true
  version: 2
```

then run:

```
$ sudo netplan generate
$ sudo netplan apply
```

this should help with any network dropouts.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do `UseRoutes=no`, but activate `UseGateway=yes`. You may take a look at my default config.

`/etc/systemd/network/default.network`

```
[Match]
Type=!loopback

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=yes

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[DHCPv4]
UseRoutes=no
UseGateway=yes
```